# Can't find error on definition of TextEdit Item Delegate

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qtgui, qdialog

Well, the error that appears is the following

```
...\build-ChequesV2-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\texteditdelegate.o:-1: In function `ZN16TextEditDelegateC2EP7QObject':

ChequesV2\texteditdelegate.cpp:8: error: undefined reference to `vtable for TextEditDelegate'
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have read the code a lot of times, and I can't find where the error is, I have compared it with the codes of other 2 delegates and it seems to be all right.

here is the header:

```
#ifndef TEXTEDITDELEGATE_H
#define TEXTEDITDELEGATE_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class TextEditDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TextEditDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                          const QModelIndex &index) const;

    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                      const QModelIndex &index) const;

};

#endif // TEXTEDITDELEGATE_H
```

And the implementation:

```
#include "texteditdelegate.h"

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QInputDialog>



TextEditDelegate::TextEditDelegate(QObject *parent): QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{

}

QWidget *TextEditDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
    const QStyleOptionViewItem &/* option */,
    const QModelIndex &/* index */) const
{
    QInputDialog *editor = new QInputDialog(parent);
    editor->setOption(QInputDialog::UsePlainTextEditForTextInput);
    editor->setInputMode(QInputDialog::TextInput);
    editor->setLabelText("Ingrese el concepto del cheque");

    return editor;
}


void TextEditDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor,
                                    const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QString value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString();

    QInputDialog *inputDialog = static_cast<QInputDialog*>(editor);
    inputDialog->setTextValue(value);
}


void TextEditDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                                   const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QInputDialog *inputDialog = static_cast<QInputDialog*>(editor);
    if (!inputDialog) return;

    model->setData(index, inputDialog->textValue()/*, Qt::EditRole*/);
}
```

and here is the call:

```
view = new QTableView;
view->setModel(tableProxy);
view->setItemDelegateForColumn(COLUMNADECONCEPTO, new TextEditDelegate(view));
```

Although commenting the last line changes nothing, the error still shows.

Comment: Do not add "solved" to the question. If you have an answer that is *different* than the answers already posted, you're welcome to answer your own question. Please edit your question so as not to contain the answer.

Comment: Although I answered my question myself BEFORE the guy below did, I edited my question so it doesn't contain the answer.

Comment: @user2348235: "the guy" is asking you if you inherit from QWidget by any chance. ;) Btw, you asked for explanation, so I gave it. Hope, it helped, but yeah as Kuba said, you are free to post your own solution in general. Although, it looks obscure when you do not provide enough information in the question.

Comment: Laszlo your explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be static_cast'ing a `QWidget` pointer. That is not a good idea.

```
QInputDialog *inputDialog = static_cast<QInputDialog*>(editor);
```

In short, static_cast is meant to be used for situations where you do know that at compilation-time that it is safe to cast from one type to another.

However, in this case, it is a runtime decision that cannot be evaluated as you expect it during the compilation time. You need to use dynamic_cast in such cases with C++, but in the Qt world, qobject_cast is even better when dealing with QObjects.

> Plus TextEditDelegate(QObject *parent = 0); Should change to this: TextEditDelegate(QWidget *parent = 0);

That is probably red-herring, and false conclusion. It should work with QObject, too.